# getting undefined when getting each component in browser console using vuejs

Tags: javascript, console, vue.js, vuejs2

when i type this(`$vm0.$children.forEach(tab => console.log(tab.name));` in console getting undefined
iam just learning vuejs and creating components.
my html file is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.5.1/css/bulma.css">
    <style type="text/css">body {padding-top:40px; }</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root" class="container">
        <tabs>
            <tab name="About Us" :selected="true">
                <h1>Here is the content for About us tab.</h1>
            </tab>
            <tab name="About Our Culture">
                <h1>Here is the content for cukture tab.</h1>
            </tab>
            <tab name="Contact tab">
                <h1>Here is the content for contact us tab</h1>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </div>
    <script src="js/11.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my js code is here

```
Vue.component('tabs', {
template: `
        <div>
            <div class="tabs">
              <ul>
                <li class="is-active"><a>Pictures</a></li>
                <li><a>Music</a></li>
                <li><a>Videos</a></li>
                <li><a>Documents</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tabs-details">
                <slot></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
`,
mounted() {
    console.log(this.$children);
}
});

Vue.component('tab',{
template: `
    <div><slot></slot></div>
`,
props: {
    name: { required : true }
}
})

new Vue({

el: "#root"

})
```

Comment: Where do you ever define `$vm0`?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @thanksd i defined in tabs component in vue DevTools

Comment: @FortheName I want  to get all the tab component in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this mistake

```
$vm0 is current element in Vue
```

When i click a element in Devtools it is defined as $vm0 like html devtools
you can find its properties and methods,
you can change prperties and its values like

```
$vm0.message = "Hello World"
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more while adding answer.